# Reading compressed csv file without header with the Java implementation of Apache Arrow

Tags: java, csv, header, apache-arrow, duckdb

The following code is based on an example available in the Java Arrow documentation for reading Parquet files, which I've updated so that instead of Parquet it uses a CSV file. Then, using DuckDb I can query the CSV file through SQL.

```
import org.apache.arrow.c.ArrowArrayStream;
import org.apache.arrow.c.Data;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.file.FileFormat;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.file.FileSystemDatasetFactory;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.jni.NativeMemoryPool;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.scanner.ScanOptions;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.scanner.Scanner;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.source.Dataset;
import org.apache.arrow.dataset.source.DatasetFactory;
import org.apache.arrow.memory.BufferAllocator;
import org.apache.arrow.memory.RootAllocator;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader;
import org.duckdb.DuckDBConnection;

import java.net.URI;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class ArrowDuckDb {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URI uri = URI.create("file:/tmp/temp.csv");

        ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions(/*batchSize*/ 32768);
        try (BufferAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator();
             ArrowArrayStream stream = ArrowArrayStream.allocateNew(allocator);
                DatasetFactory datasetFactory = new FileSystemDatasetFactory(allocator,
                        NativeMemoryPool.getDefault(), FileFormat.CSV, uri.toString());) {

             Dataset dataset = datasetFactory.finish();
             Scanner scanner = dataset.newScan(options);
             ArrowReader reader = scanner.scanBatches();

           Data.exportArrayStream(allocator, reader, stream);

           Class.forName("org.duckdb.DuckDBDriver");
           try (DuckDBConnection conn = (DuckDBConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:duckdb:")) {
                 conn.registerArrowStream("testStream", stream);

                 try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testStream")) {
                            while(rs.next()) {
                                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                            }
                        }
                 }
            }
        }


}
```

This works very well. However, I am interested in using the above code for CSV files **without a header**. Is there a way to define the header myself while reading the file with Apache Arrow?

Comment: It does not appear to be possible.  The way you would normally do that (in the C++ datasets library that the Java code is wrapping) is by creating a custom "file format".  However, it appears that `FileFormat.CSV` is an enum and there is no way to customize the created file format.  So it does not appear that this capability is a part of the Java bindings at the moment.